# Showing updates in Facebook

Tags: facebook

A previous answer stated:

> For example, if you untick Life Events, they will never get displayed no matter what frequency you choose.

Wrong. I’ve unticked the *Comments and Likes* setting for everyone, but I keep getting those updates.

So-and-so "Likes" such-and-such... with an entire history of everyone who ever posted to some Facebook thread three times removed from me. I do not want to see "Likes." Does Facebook not work correctly or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you seeing these likes on your main newsfeed or from within individual list newsfeeds?

Comment: Are you seeing these in your main news feed or the ticker? Currently, only privacy settings of the individual news items affect what shows up in the ticker. The settings you refer to affect the main news feed.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities here:

1. You have not refreshed.
2. You are looking at the profile/wall of some friend of yours' whereas the setting only apply to your own News feed.
3. The posts that you see contains link to some "Page" which is "Sponsored".
4. The posts shouldn't show up but they are as they have received a lot of comments/likes from your friends and thus qualify as "Important" updates.